# MySQL: How to clean MySQL from RHEL5?

Tags: mysql, linux, configuration, troubleshooting

I have installed MySQL 5.1.73 community edition through RPM. It was working fine.
I uninstalled this version by using `yum remove mysql-server` command.
I wanted to upgrade MySQL from 5.1.73 to 5.6.19 community edition.
Then I installed it by `sudo rpm -i /u000/MySQL-server-5.6.19-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm` command.
After installation, I was able to start mysql by issuing `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`. 
After this, I tried to install `MySQL-shared-compat-5.6.19-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm` using RPM command. But, it is giving conflict message with mysql 5.1.73 - `install of MySQL-server-5.6.19-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.73-4.el6.x86_64`. 
It is same for `MySQL-client-5.6.19-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm`. Again, I got the similar conflict message.
After this, I tried to connect MySQL by issuing below command:

```
$ mysql -uroot -p3pkvFtaWM_PTCwJ8 
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

- How can I fix this issue and run the MySQL 5.6 as normally?
- Do I need to clean MySQL from server?

Comment: Uninstall everything. Then, from the root directory, do a "sudo find . -name "mysql*"" and then delete any files that this finds. It can be hell when you have files hanging around after an uninstall.

Comment: @Vérace: its correct that after uninstalling it's a hell to remove all the files. I tried it by using locate mysql command to list all the files and delete those by issuing `rm -r ` command. But, still some library files there...

Comment: :-) - just make **absolutely** sure that you have deleted **everything** before installing a new system. Or, you could go the source code route - I now find this preferable.

Comment: should I delete files under `/var/spool/up2date` directory like `/var/spool/up2date/mysql51-build-1-9.el5.x86_64.hdr`?

Comment: Also, should I delete files like `./usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/sos/plugins/mysql.pyc
./usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/sos/plugins/mysql.pyo
./usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/sos/plugins/mysql.py`

Comment: I installed everything and then install by using `rpm -ivh MySQL-server-5.6.14-1.el6.x86_64.rpm`. service started successfully. But, when tried to connect using `mysql -uroot -pdefaultpassword` it is giving `-bash: mysql: command not found`

Comment: Issue the command "which mysql" - that will tell you where your executables are.

Comment: Te conflict prevent you from installing the mysql-client. I have detailed the steps below, make sure to install MySQL-server and MySQL-client.

Answer (score 1):

Search for mysql-related packages that are now installed: `rpm -qa | grep -i mysql`

Delete any packages like mysql, mysql-server, mysql-client, mysql-shared, mysql-shared-compat, mysql-libs. `yum remove mysql-server` You do **not** need to remove mysql library bindings like python-mysqldb, php-mysql, etc., unless they had a dependency with some of the previous packages.

I recommend you to install the Oracle MySQL yum repositories, that will make the installing and maintenance much easier, *unless you know what you are doing and want more control over your packages*. An installation guide is detailed here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-yum-repo-quick-guide/en/index.html Basically, it involves creating a .repo file and yum update.

Comment: below 2 questions: (A) yum is supporting for removing but not for installing. I am getting error like 401 autorization error in accessing yu repository mirror. (B) is it necessary to install mysql-shared-library before installing mysql-server and mysql-client? If I install mysql-shared-compat-library after installation of server and client, will there be any issue?

Comment: (A) Make sure you install this: http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-community-release-el5-5.noarch.rpm In any case, `yum localinstall` should do a similar thing as `rpm -i` (B) if the repository is installed, both the client and the server install the shared libraries automatically. As far as I know (I may be wrong) you have to manually install server *and* client.

Comment: How do I check that repository is installed? I installed server and client manually.

Comment: `yum repolist enabled | grep "mysql.*-community.*"`